# Social media share not picking up meta tags in react-app via react-helmet or react-meta-tags

Tags: reactjs, frontend, meta-tags

I have an application built with React.js and I want to customize the look of the URL that is shared on social media using HTML meta tags.

I have tried to use react-helmet and react-meta-tags that are used for adding meta tags, but they didn't help.

Is the only solution to this problem to use server-side rendering or there is a way to handle it from front-end only?

Comment: Are they `og:` tags? Here's the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) from facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about what you trying to achieve. The concept divides into two choices. Server side or client side.

If client side you should be comfortable with *react-helmet*. What I think about why you can't accomplish *react-helmet* is you didn't remove static *meta* codes from your **index.html**. What happening is you might are getting client side dynamic meta that is generated from helmet but being replaced by already static meta tags from **index.html**. So remove them and it should work fine...

Now come to dynamic *SEO* for **OG (Open Graph)** Meta Tags without **SSR**. There are few packages that pre render dynamic meta tags that might help to solve your problems without **SSR** implemented on your *React App*.

- [react-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap) is the solution you are looking for.
- Look at       **[THIS](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/213)** discussion.
- [Strategies to SEO on React](https://medium.com/mixed-marketing-technology/our-solution-to-make-seo-work-for-a-react-js-site-rankwatch-blog-9a311b86fb5f)
- [Using Express as backend](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/)

Hope you found them useful. cheers...!!!

Answer (score -2):

first install :
npm install react-helmet --save

and then Add meta tag :
like!

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <title>App Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="https://malikgabroun.com" />
            </Helmet>
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

EXAMPLE:

```html
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import React from 'react';
const Seo = ({ title, description, pathSlug, keywords }) => {
  const url = `https://malikgabroun.com/${pathSlug}`
    return (
<Helmet htmlAttributes={{ lang: 'en' }} title={title} meta={[
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: description,
        },
        {
          name: 'keywords',
          content: keywords.join(),
        },
        ]}
    links={[
     {
          rel: 'canonical',
          href: url,
      },
    ]}
    />
 );
}
export default Seo;
```

For more details go for this link and read it.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-add-metadata-in-react-using-react-helmet-6dd316d146c2

Comment: I've tried but it still didn't work on social media

Comment: Social media read the `og:` tags from your webpage. Those are the one you need to setup. I strongly recommend using the [Sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). You may need to click the **Scrape again** button to remove your page from the facebook cache and re-fetch it.